# EasyAdmin 4 Image Field preserve value on edit

Tags: easyadmin, symfony6

I am building simple admin panel using Easy Admin 4 and Symfony 6. Can't figure out how to preserve uploaded image value when editing entity. Image preview is not visible on Edit form also. Code is very simple:

```
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
            TextField::new('name')->setColumns(4),
            UrlField::new('url')->setColumns(4),
            ImageField::new('icon')
                ->setUploadDir('public/assets/images/')
                ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('assets/images/[slug]-[contenthash].[extension]')
                ->setColumns(4),
            TextareaField::new('description')->setColumns(12)->onlyOnForms(),
        ];
    }
```

Icon field is set to null on each edit. What am I missing?

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I think that if EasyAdmin is not able to access the image (to get the file size and such...) the field value will be blank. It should keep the value otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue right now that I could solve with allowing "nullable=true" for the image url property on my entity.

Seems like when "not changing" the file during edit, null is passed and this triggers an error on the validation